# How can the morphology of a language be formally represented i.e. computerized?

Tags: computational-linguistics, morphology

Languages can have very different morphologies. For instance, Sanskrit has a morphology that is heavily based on the root, and the combination of roots with other roots results in new words (it is actually famous for having the most productive root-derivational system of any extant language). Arabic, on the other hand, has a triliteral morphology, where prefixes and vowel changes rule.

What system of representation exists that allows us to represent the structure of Sanskrit and Arabic with equal ease?

Comment: In other words, "What is the representational theory of words in human language". There are thousands of theories, including a theory that there is no morphological components. You need to narrow the question down.

Comment: @user6726 Let me try to narrow it down: in programming language theory, there is EBNF for representing almost all programming languages. What do linguists think as of A.D. 2023 is the best framework for representing morphologies as different as Sanskrit and Arabic?

Comment: You could look at two-level morphology. This was the hot issue when I was at university in the 90s; not sure if there have been many new developments in that area since.

Comment: Distributed Morphology is the current leading theory: it's a variety of item and arrangement morphology.

Comment: @user6726 Thank you! That's the ticket! If you would like, you can turn your comment into a full answer so I can award you a green checkmark and some karma.

Comment: @user6726 Could you explain why this question was closed?  It surprises me a bit.  I'd be happy to make the edits to get it re-opened, but I realise I don't understand why it was closed.

Comment: I thought it needed to be narrowed down since the intent was not clear, but really it closed because of the diamond hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two answers, depending on what you mean by "morphology".

**Two-level morphology** is an older theory from 1983, by Kimmo Koskenniemi with contributions by Lauri Karttunen, which is a finite-state computational model of how underlying forms map to pronunciations. It accounts for the fact that in Finnish, /kettun/ surfaces as [ketun] and /vete/ surfaces as [vesi]. I don't understand how it handles the basic syntax of word-formation, e.g. marking subjects in perfective vs. imperfective in Arabic. I don't recall having seen any use of the model in linguistics beyond the mid 90's.

**Distributed morphology**, is the leading theory of morphology in contemporary linguistic theory, and was initiated by Halle & Marantz 1993. This is a more syntactically-oriented theory which posits that word structure is fundamentally syntactic, but post-syntactic operations can obscure the syntactic unity. It is basically an item-and-arrangement type of theory. It relies on a lexicon, an "exponent list", that would contain affixes (for example) plus operations that ultimately give you a phonological underlying form, and at that point you are done with morphology.  (Two-level morphology doesn't have a phonology, it merges the two components into one).

Answer (score 1):

> What system of representation exists that allows us to represent the structure of Sanskrit and Arabic with equal ease?

It sounds a bit like you want something formal and rule-based, but the reality, as of 2023 is that equal ease - and better coverage and accuracy overall - is clearly best achieved with language-agnostic **deep learning representations**, like [word embeddings](https://machinetranslate.org/word-embeddings) and [byte-pair encoding](https://machinetranslate.org/byte-pair-encoding) and [attention](https://machinetranslate.org/attention).

In the old days, before deep learning, we would hand-craft parsers, morphological analysers and synthesisers and so on.  It was not very accurate, and it was a lot of work, but it was transparent and interpretable.

Now, we just throw raw text to models that know what a [token](https://machinetranslate.org/token) is and not much more.  This approach works roughly equally well across all languages, given the same amount and quality of data.

But - and I imagine this drives certain linguists and engineers nuts - the vectors and their dimensions don't have names, the tokens and byte pairs don't necessarily correspond to words, and neither have distinct representations for distinct senses of homographs.

Overall though, as we see, this is a better way to build systems, with ever fewer exceptions.

Consider that some languages encode more information in morphology, and others in syntax.

Comment: Deep learning is a black box. It is statistically likely to produce good results, but the inner model of the transformer is an enigma. That makes it very hard to generalize. Formal and rule-based systems are easy to generalize. In particular, formal and rule-based systems allow for the possibility of discovering a new system of morphology not utilized by any existing language.

Comment: @HolyKnowledge Can I ask, what is your goal?  If you're actually building something that's very different than "discovering a new system of morphology not utilized by any existing language".

Comment: By the way, I would not say that the Transformer is an enigma.  There are some aspects of it that are not well understood, but there are plenty that are, it's open-source code.  Also, it's a bit of diversion, because it's mainly concerned with sequences which correspond to syntax, but if you had asked this question in 2015, pre-Transformer, my answer would have been roughly the same, but only mentioned word embeddings and byte-pair encodings, but not attention.